# Передача данных из запроса в переменные

Tags: mysql, node.js

Доброго времени суток.
Подскажите как к примеру из запроса вытащить полученные данные в переменные.
В таблице user хранятся данные id, name, lvl, exp необходимо передать эти данные в переменные.

```
DB.Handle.query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE name = 'Herald'", function(e, r, f){   
        if(r.length >= 1)
          {

              //Логика для передачи данных в переменные 
              console.log(r);                  

          }
          else
          {
            //Ничего нет выполняем логику
            console.log(r);
          }
      });
```

Comment: У вас по идее должен вернуться массив пользователей, но я не понял какие данные и в какие переменные вы хотите передать, `let users = r;` так чтоли? ) И чтобы приходил один юзер в запросе ставьте `LIMIT 1`

Comment: при запросе в переменную r поступает ответ [ RowDataPacket { id: 12, name: 'Herald', level: 50, exp: 123 } ]
нужно полученный результат куда то записать чтобы дальше работать